# Is the original author allowed to peer review an edit?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I've submitted an edit to the linked answer because the answer is demonstrably incorrect, and the original author refuses to accept the evidence provided to him/her that it is demonstrably incorrect. The edit was rejected by the author them-self, because apparently the author has the required reputation to peer review.

Is this something that's allowed? If so, I think this should be changed because, in this case, it leads to the spread of false information and prevents the accepted answer from being corrected due to a hostile author. Given that the answer is the accepted answer, people looking for an answer to this question are likely to get information that is simply incorrect.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20053771

Comment: The post author can always accept/reject edits to their posts.

Comment: And you shouldn't edit an answer because you think is "wrong". Comment under it, and/or provide an alternative answer. But putting words in someone else's mouth is not nice.

Comment: you removed 99% of the original answer and replaced it, I wouldn't call this an edit, I would call this a massacre as what it would become doesn't resemble the original in any shape or form

Comment: Yeah. My intentions were to correct the answer, because it is the accepted answer and I'm not convinced it would be possible to change the accepted answer to a correct one. I understand now that edits aren't the correct way to go about an incorrect answer.

Answer (score 19):

Yes, the author can review edits to their post. However, it doesn't matter what rep they have- They can *always* unilaterally review suggested edits to their post.

The author of the post is in the best position to tell if an edit changes the intent of their post. Yes, some authors are irresponsible with this power and will reject good edits just because they don't want their post edited, but I'd contend that the vast majority of authors aren't this way.

Now, much more importantly: *Don't edit answers to change what they say.* If it's completely wrong and not just a typo, don't change it to make it right. Instead, post your own answer. If it's based a lot on the original, be sure you attribute that work to the other user and don't claim it as your own.

More specifically, it looks like your edit *completely changed* the original answer. Don't do that! It's putting words in another person's mouth, and if others find that information to be incorrect... They're the ones that will be downvoted for *your* work. That's not nice.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the detailed response. Very helpful and informative.